# Getting all of the items from an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have a `ListFragment` backed by an `ArrayAdapter` that gets populated by a `Loader`. When the user clicks on one of the items, I want to pass a reference to the selected item, as well as the rest of the list items to another fragment. My question is how should I get all of the items from the adapter? Here are the possibilities that I see:

**1. Keep a reference to the backing `List`**

Create the adapter like so:

```
List<DomainObject> items = new ArrayList<DomainObject>();
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DomainObject>(getActivity(), R.layout.mine, items);
```

and then simply pass `items` or a copy of it to the next activity.

The downside I see of this is that I'm relying on the undocumented fact that the same list that I pass to the constructor contains the items later on.

**2. Iterate through the adapter**

When an item is clicked, iterate through the adapter and build up the list. This seems like an unnecessary amount of work. The items are contained in a `List` in the adapter and I'm manually copying each item to a new list.

**3. Keep a separate list of items when adding to adapter**

Before adding an item to the adapter, add it to a separate list that I maintain in the fragment. This is also wasteful as the list of items is copied in the `ArrayAdapter` and the fragment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution that I've gone with in the meantime is just to not use `ArrayAdapter`. In cases where you're fighting against this API, it seems like it's better just to use the less fully-featured (and complex) `BaseAdapter`. You can read more about the decision to go with `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` in this article: [Android Adapter Good Practices](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices).

Comment: While that article is mostly good, I'd ignore his whole thread safety section. He's completely wrong about why there are suppose to be locks (due to filtering which occurs on a background thread) and that the `ArrayAdapter` will already crash if `notifyDataSetChanged()` is invoked on anything but the UI thread.

Comment: @scompt.com I think the link you've posted is wrong explaining ArrayAdapter. It seems to explain only ArrayAdapter<String>. I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: From the page you linked... "Can only display text." => Wrong. "Forces you to provide a list of CharSequence items..." => Wrong "Requires that you provide a layout resource that contains only a TextView" => Wrong. Allmost all assumptions are wrong... I dont mean ArrayAdapter is better than BaseAdapter but basics are wrong.

Comment: Piwaï not found!

Answer (score 37):

I'm a little late to the game, but I've run up against a similar issue.

One way to deal with #1 would be to maintain the reference to the list within a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, so that your reuse is controlled by the adapter object.

Something like:

```
public class DomainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DomainObject> {

    private final List<DomainObject> items;

    public DomainAdapter(Context context, List<DomainObject> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.mine, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<DomainObject> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note. If you plan on filtering the adapter at some point, this method has the potential to fail. Performing a filter will, internal to the ArrayAdapter, create an whole new instance of the List. Which means your externally defined `items` will no longer be the same list. Which means it'll fall out of sync if modifications are later made. You can read more about it here: http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/constructor-woes-androids-arrayadapter/

Answer (score 0):

A quick test says that method 1 works. It seems the quickest and cleanest, but since it is undocumented you may want to test it across the intended platforms and whenever they update in case the underlying structure of ArrayAdapter changes.

I am using compile SDK version 22 and min SDK Version 10.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to "keep a reference to the List" BUT not passing "items" variable/parameter to the Constructor:

`List<DomainObject> items = new ArrayList<DomainObject>();
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DomainObject>(getActivity(), R.layout.mine);`

In this way you only instantiate the ArrayList as an empty array and you will have to manage YOUR list by yourself.

Answer (score -2):

I think first method is best way to do this.

I dont think, Data would be original for the Another Activity. because, You would pass items through bundle, so the object is written on bundle first and then in next Activity we read from bundle.

However, if you are using some other way to pass the list, use `list.clone()` to create new Object, instead of passing original one.