# Android ArrayAdapter, how to get the collection given to its constructor

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I made a `class` which inherits from an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Member>{

    public myAdapter() {
        super(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.id.myLayout, myList);
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // What do I write here in order to get the given list?
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `constructor`, I give it a `list` in the `super` function as parameter.
Where did this collection disappear? How may I have acces to it without making another attribute in the class?

Comment: why do you want to access it ? you have `getCount` and `getItem` for reading, and `add`, `remove`... for writing.

Comment: How can I get an item by its index?

Comment: are you serious? you could not find this information in the documentation?

Comment: `Adapter.getItem(int position)`

Comment: thanks leo. njzk2 you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the [ArrayAdapter source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter), you'll see that what your are trying to do is not native possible.

This is the ArrayAdapter constuctor that you used

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

The list, you pass it, is stored in a variable called `mOriginalValues`. And you can access it only using other methods, like `add(T object),` or `remove(T object)`, etc, but no method will return the entire list

If you want maintain a trace of this list you need to store your list in the adapter and then use a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15363873/1584654)