# Filtered list item opens the original list items' activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, android-search

After a tremendous amount of time searching in here, and everywhere else I am hopeless to find a solution.

So here is my problem.

**I have created a list-view and on top of that I added a search-bar.**

When I use the search-bar, to filter the results... when I click on item 7, instead of opening the specific clicked activity i.e. 7, it always starts from the first one.

I am looking forward to your help guys; because I need it!

Comment: seriously now, is this the issue Tasos, the title?

Comment: You can not start another activity base on position in your case so try open another activity base on clicked item some unique identification.

Comment: Hi Haresh, could you elaborate on what you said a little bit more? With an example of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Group extends ListActivity {

 // ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> searchResults;

 // ArrayList that will hold the original Data
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> originalValues;
LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.grouplist);
final EditText searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
ListView playersListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

final EditText searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
ListView playersListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// these arrays are just the data that
// I'll be using to populate the ArrayList
String names[] = {/*list of names*/ };
String teams[] = {/*list of teams*/};
Integer[] photos = {R.drawable.... /*list of drawables*/};
Integer[] id ={/*Position*/};

 originalValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

// temporary HashMap for populating the Items in the ListView
HashMap<String, Object> temp;

// total number of rows in the ListView
int noOfPlayers = names.length;

// now populate the ArrayList players
for (int i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++) {
temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

temp.put("name", names[i]);
temp.put("team", teams[i]);
temp.put("photo", photos[i]);
temp.put("id", id[i]);

// add the row to the ArrayList
    originalValues.add(temp);
 }
    // searchResults=OriginalValues initially
  searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(originalValues);

final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.players, searchResults);

 // finally,set the adapter to the default ListView
playersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // get the text in the EditText
    String searchString = searchBox.getText().toString();
    int textLength = searchString.length();

    // clear the initial data set
    searchResults.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < originalValues.size(); i++) {
        String playerName = originalValues.get(i).get("name").toString();
        if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {
            // compare the String in EditText with Names in the
            // ArrayList
            if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0, textLength)))
                searchResults.add(originalValues.get(i));
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,  int  after) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});


// listening to single list item on click
    playersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,      int position, long id) {

        int pos=Integer.ParseInt(searchResults.get(position).get("id").toString());
             switch (pos) {
              case 0:
               Intent newActivity = new Intent(TeamsList.this, Barca.class);
               startActivity(newActivity);
               break;
              case 1:
               etc...
             }
       }
    }
 });

}
```

Custom adapter Class:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Strings) {

// let android do the initializing :)
super(context, textViewResourceId, Strings);
}

// class for caching the views in a row
private class ViewHolder {
ImageView photo;
TextView name, team;

}

ViewHolder viewHolder;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.players, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    // cache the views
    viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    viewHolder.team = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team);

    //Take one textview in listview design named id
    viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);


    // link the cached views to the convert view
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

  } else 
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

 int photoId = (Integer) searchResults.get(position).get("photo");

 // set the data to be displayed
viewHolder.photo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(photoId));
viewHolder.name.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("name").toString());
viewHolder.team.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("team").toString());
viewHolder.id.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("id").toString());


// return the view to be displayed
return convertView;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I change something in your code. Hope it works. Its easily done when u use entity for setting data in textviews

Comment: thank you for your replies! :-)Following your suggestion I inflated the line of Integer[] id ={/*Position*/}; with all my R.layouts (If I am wrong, please give me a 1 /2 line example of how to do it). Once I save an clean the project I get the following errors: 1) Multiple markers at this line
 - id cannot be resolved or is, not a field in the line of code: //Take one textview in listview design named id
        viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id); and 2) id cannot be resolved or is not a field,in viewHolder.id.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("id").toString());

Comment: ImageView photo;
TextView name, team,id;  Declare id in viewholder like this

Comment: Hi akhil, when I do as you say, indeed it solves the issues. Only one thing remains though which is in the following line: viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);      Error: id cannot be resolved or is not a field... is the error it in the xml files (I have also included the xml files above)?  Thanks again

Comment: yep, tried everything that was suggested so far but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant find correct position on listview item click. so u can use one textview with visibility="Gone" and insert the position in that textview in every row. now u can easily access position while clicking on item with the value of textview which shows perfect position. Hope it works. Thanx

Comment: viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id); add one textview in viewholder and set text of that textview to the position. I think it works.

Comment: first off, you are right that is my problem. Also, if it is not to much to ask, could you show me how to do it in the specific code above because I am trying for days to find a solution and feel hopeless right now. I thank you and I apologize for all the trouble

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Adapter is populated once but with search results it gets overViewed by the searched items so on clicking it refers to the original items of list instead of the filtered list once , so we have to use the filtered lists' positions instead of the original one, i also faced this problem, try this:

In your **listView.setOnItemClickListener**

```
playersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    //Object objFilteredItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //String a = searchResults.get(position);

    switch (Integer.parseInt((String) adapter.getItem(position))) {
    case 0:..
     Intent newActivity = new Intent(TeamsList.this,Barca.class);
     startActivity(newActivity);
     break;

    case 1:
     etc...
     break;
   }
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As from my previously answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562996/1450945), you have to override the `getItem(position)` method in your `CustomAdapter`. You are setting the `onItemClick` somewhat correctly but the list adapter doesn't know what exactly it's getting from `getItem(position)`.

**EDIT** (details): You need to add something like this in your custom adapter -

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
```

You should already have the `list` in your custom adapter. If not, you can add a list reference to your `CustomAdapter`:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list;
```

Then setting it using a setter in your `Group` activity:

```
customAdapter.setList(searchResults);
```

Comment: Also @justarandomguy you might want to reconsider using `ArrayAdapter`. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650121/getting-all-of-the-items-from-an-arrayadapter