# How to start new intent after search-filtering listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

Hi guys I have a question:

I created a listview, with search-bar etc . So when I click on an item (through switch-case) the selected new activity opens and there are no problems.

you can see the code here:

[Filtered list item opens the original list items' activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663932/filtered-list-item-opens-the-original-list-items-activity)

The problems start when I filter the listview, with the search-bar, and  instead of opening the selected activity (let us say activity 10), it throws me back to activity 1 and so forth.

What I have figured out so far is that most probably the CustomAdapter somehow mixes my activities and does not know which activity was chosen; hence, it throws me back to the beginning.

Please guys, I am trying for over a month to solve that issue and still no hope in the horizon.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: post your code for customadapter.

Comment: hi fabin, if you click on the link above you will be redirected to the code  just scroll down a little (its after the switch-case). I have included all xml and so forth, so as to give you guys a complete picture of it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have given click event based on the position of listview. eg:
players = {"test1","test2","test3"}

CASE 1: when nothing is searched:
      first position has player test1

case 2: when user search test2.
   Now listview search for test2 and find only one instance of this, and searchlist will have only one player and it will be at the first position. Since you have given click event based on position it, first  row will always take to Barca

**UPDATE:**

you need to change your Code as below

Group.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Group extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<Players> originalValues;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int noOfPlayers = 10;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grouplist);
    final EditText searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    ListView playersListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    originalValues = new ArrayList<Players>();

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++) {
        // here you initialise the class with your own data
        Players players = new Players(i, "name" + i, "team", R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        originalValues.add(players);
    }

    final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.players, originalValues);

    playersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String searchString = searchBox.getText().toString();
            int textLength = searchString.length();

            adapter.clearSearchResult();

            for (int i = 0; i < originalValues.size(); i++) {
                String playerName = originalValues.get(i).getName();
                if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {
                    // compare the String in EditText with Names in the
                    // ArrayList
                    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0, textLength)))
                        adapter.addSeachResult(originalValues.get(i));
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


    playersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch ((int) adapter.getItemId(position)) {
                case 0:
                        Intent newActivity = new    Intent(Group.this, Barca.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    etc
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Players> searchResults;

ViewHolder viewHolder;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Players> results) {
    searchResults = new ArrayList<>(results);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.players, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.team = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    int photoId = (Integer) searchResults.get(position).getPicture();

    viewHolder.photo.setImageDrawable(parent.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(photoId));
    viewHolder.name.setText(searchResults.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.team.setText(searchResults.get(position).getTeam());


    return convertView;

}

public void clearSearchResult() {
    searchResults.clear();
}

public void addSeachResult(Players result) {
    this.searchResults.add(result);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView photo;
    TextView name, team;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return searchResults.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchResults.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return searchResults.get(position).getId();
}
}
```

New Class called Player.java

```
public class Players {

public Players(int id,String name,String team,int picture){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.team = team;
    this.picture = picture;
}

private int id;
private String name;
private String team;
private int picture;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public int getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(int picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabin.... The list consists of 30 players (!), and not only 2. When I change my code as you describe I get: "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token". So, do I have to go for:  if -else if - else if - else if - ... - else,  nested statements? Finally: the word, "test1", in your code do I write it exactly like this or do I change it with something else?

Comment: I have edited my answer and made sure it will work this time.. :)

Comment: Hi fabin, yes it works! :) HOWEVER, now all data from the original code does not appear. For instance, lets us say for : name "Messi, team "Barca" and his drawable/picture - so, instead of getting this data all I get is a list with: the launcher icon for all players, the word "team" appears where Barca or Real should appear and instead of "Messi" or "Ronaldo" I get : name0, name 1 etc. In other words, I believe that the code does not populate the listview. Am I missing something or have I messed up things? :(

Comment: I have added a comment, if you noticed. Here I have used a loop to create 10 object of player in arraylist. You must remove this loop and create each player and add it to orginalvalues

Comment: I deleted my last comments. I got what you meant and am currently working on it. So far it goes smoothly; regardless if I have to add about 50 original values (At this stage I seriously do not mind it). Respect Fabin, you solved a problem that was killing me for over one month. If I may ask, what is the theory behind of what you did, is there a link to read all about it (So as to better understand your solution)? Once again, thank youuuuuuuuu!!! :)

Comment: Thats great.. Glad i could help. Now theory behind it is old. It follows mvc (Model View Controller)model ie. Player.java is model class. This class represent a real life object. For as many Player in real life you can create as many object of Player.java in your program.      View is your xml. View act as the interface between user and the program     Your Activity or Adapter is your controller which is the mediator between data and views. So you Activity has objects of views(Edittext,Textview) and models (Player).

Comment: I know it is difficult to understand. I would suggest you to start from simpler programs like questionnaires. Try out slidenerd from youtube . Great guy and Great videos. If you are into reading I would suggest  [book on android](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321804334/samplepages/0321804333.pdf)

Comment: Once again I thank you Fabin :-) ... PS: I have upvoted your answer but it says something about 15 reputation points, regarding me that is, for making the upvote appear public ???!!! In any event, if I earned that points I will definitely come to upvote it publicly