# Android search list invisible by default? Can it be done?

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview, search-engine

Hi guys I have a question:

In short, I have a listview, with a searchbar on top of it, I am also able to start my other activities after filtering the results etc; basically everything works fine and sweet.

My question is this:
When launching the main activity the listview is visible (obviously enough). Is there a way to make the listview invisible and only after typing in the searchbar to make the results of the listview become visible? Something like an in app search thing; or am I just imagining things?

I hope that I am not too confusing with what I wrote above.

I am looking forward to your replies and I thank you in advance.

Comment: yeah it's easy, set your listview's visibility to INVISIBLE by default and add a text watcher to your search bar, whenever you have non-empty string, make the listview visible

Comment: hi sarthak, thanks for your quick reply. Is there an example code that I could look up what you just told me?

Comment: i don't know if you can get the exact implemented solution but you surely can search step by step. It's quite simple stuff.

Comment: will try and worst case I will chase you in stackexchange :-P Thank you :-)

Comment: have tried everything. I got the textwatcher down but regarding listview INVISIBLE, no solution. what is the exact code for it and where to I insert it?

Comment: post what you have written here and i will gladly help you :)

Comment: you can pretty much check the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405610/how-to-start-new-intent-after-search-filtering-listview

Answer (score 0):

Go this way:
set your listview visibility to gone or invisible from your xml file:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Now apply textwatcher on searchbar edittext

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //put your search logic here and populate listview.
                //after populating listview set its visibility to visible
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //and set listview visibility to GONE again when user erase all text from search edittext
                if(s.length() == 0){
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: it does not work unfortunately. Maybe the code, which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405610/how-to-start-new-intent-after-search-filtering-listview, could help you... I guess