# Hiding Listview until search is initiated

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview, hidden

I have a question:
I have a listview (from custom adapter) with a searchbar on top of it. Everything works ok, the only thing I need is when opening the activity to keep the listview hidden, or invisible, until the search has started in the searchbar (in other words, to keep the listview hidden until I start typing something in the searchbar).

You can find the code here:

[How to start new intent after search-filtering listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405610/how-to-start-new-intent-after-search-filtering-listview)

Plus a suggested solution, which unfortunately did not work, you can see here:

[Android search list invisible by default? Can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573960/android-search-list-invisible-by-default-can-it-be-done)

I am looking forward to your replies guys and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `TextWatcher` to your search `EditText`. This will detect when you type something in your search:

```
EditText search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

TextWatcher method:

```
    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
         //Change the visibility here
         list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking about an AutoCompleteTextView? It requires that you load the list data into its adapter then set the adapter.

```
// Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
// Get the string array
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
// Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Google's Guide: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete).

Comment: Hi Frank, I have no issues with the search activity whatsoever. All I want is when I open the activity, in which the listview is located (ie Activity_Main) to keep the listview hidden/invisible until I start searching for something...

Comment: So you want a full screen version of the AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: No. I just want my listview to be invisible ;-)

Comment: Im sorry Im not sure what kind of action you are looking for.