# Getting all the items in an ArrayAdapter after filtering

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Related question: [Getting all of the items from an ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650121/getting-all-of-the-items-from-an-arrayadapter)

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` backed by an `ArrayAdapter`.  The list of suggestions changes in runtime.  In order for the change to be persistent I need to get a list of all items in the adapter.  What is the best way to do this?  Do I need to iterate through the list to get all the elements?

The method 1 in the aforementioned question (**keeping a reference to the backing list**) doesn't work because according to the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java), after filtering `ArrayAdapter` creates a copy of the original list and operates on it instead, and `add`ing items to the adapter no longer changes the backing list.

Using a `BaseAdapter` does not apply either, since `AutoCompleteTextView` requires a `Filterable` adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your issue, your options are:

1. Extend the base adapter and provide your own filtering.  This is probably the best, but requires the most effort.
2. Manage a list in parallel to the adapter's list, add and remove items to both lists.  This is easy, but tracking duplicate data seems dirty to me.
3. Clear the adapters filter and then grab the entire data set.  This also isn't pretty, but it works.  I don't know the use-cases for your app, so I don't know if there are any side effects to clearing the filter.

This example sets a few strings to the adapter, when the user presses a button, it clears the filter and then gets the total item count.  At this time you can iterate over the adapter items retrieving all of them.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
      stringList.add("hello");
      stringList.add("hell");
      stringList.add("help");
      stringList.add("heck");
      stringList.add("dude");
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, stringList);
      AutoCompleteTextView ac = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto_complete);
      ac.setThreshold(1);
      ac.setAdapter(adapter);

      FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            Filter f = adapter.getFilter();
            f.filter("", new Filter.FilterListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                  int count2 = adapter.getCount();
                  mainText.setText("Count is: " + count);
                  adapter.add("hellraiser");
               }
            });
         }
      });

      mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
```

Comment: But after clearing the filter, do you still need to loop and call `getItem` to retrieve the list?

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda - Yes